# override assert in lua

Tags: lua, cgi, assert

my setup board uses lighttpd to provide web UI to the board.
It uses lua and JS to draw logic.

What I am seeing is If I enter an URL as "IPofboard/somejunkhere"; its properly throwing "404 not found"
But when I fire "IPofboard/somejunk.lp" (which is some junk lua file); It produces an "assert" error for file not found. Thats how lua works.

But I want to modify/override this assert to show same custom message as "404 not found"
any idea?

I am new to lua. Is it even doable?

Comment: so somejunk.lp is found and runs, but some file it is trying to load causes an assertion failure? do you have control over what is in the .lp file?

Comment: Partially, Yes. I have /usr/share/lua/cgilua/lp.lua file, under which open(filename) call is guarded with "assert".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As lhf mentions, it is very easy to redefine any function in Lua, but I think this may not be what you need. The issue is that after you do

```
local origAssert = assert
assert = function(message) 
    do something (possibly using origAssert)
end
```

then every function call that uses assert will use your new assert function, which is probably not what you want. Instead, you can call your function in "protected" mode: this will trap the assertion as an error message, and you can then decide what to do. For example,

```
ok, ret1, ret2 = pcall(yourFunction, arg1)
if not ok then 
    do something, possibly print ret1 (the error message)
end
```

Same thing if you are requiring a module that does some initialization:

```
ok, module = pcall(require, yourModuleName)
if not ok then 
    print("ERROR:", module) -- if not ok then module is err message
end
```

Comment: Thanks. That is close to what I wanted. should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with how lighttpd embeds Lua, but in Lua you can redefine anything, including functions from the standard Lua library, such as `assert`.